# What is the difference between `pip install` and `python -m pip install`?

Tags: python, pip

On the internet, I saw them almost as interchangeable even if someone says that the latter is safer. What are the difference and which one should be used in which cases?

Comment: `python -m` runs the library module as its own script (do `python --help` to see arguments and their explanations). As to their difference, I don't think there is one fundamentally

Comment: Pip is just calling python -m pip... the reason its safer to just call python -m pip, is that you know for sure which python will get the install... where if you have multiple python installed who knows which one just pip installs to

Comment: @JoranBeasley Isn't there are a difference in pip  from `pip` and `pip3` for this already?

Comment: Yes max this is also true

Comment: @Max Maybe pip3 only refers to python3.x, you don't know to which version if you have more than one.